# Populate Combobox from SQL Server vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I'm trying to populate a combobox with data from SQL Server. This is my code so far. There are asterisks around the errors. Also, ignore the comments.

```
Private Sub frmOriginal_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connetionString As String = Nothing
    Dim sqlcon As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim sql As String = Nothing

    connetionString = "Data Source = RENEE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stocks;Integrated Security = True"
    sql = "select * from TickerSymbol"

    sqlcon = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlcon)
        adapter.SelectCommand = command
        adapter.Fill(ds)
        adapter.Dispose()
        command.Dispose()
        sqlcon.Close()

        cboID.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        cboID.ValueMember = "TickerSymbol"
        cboID.DisplayMember = "TickerSymbol"
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ")'
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub cboID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboID.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim command As New SqlCommand *(queryString, connection)*
    Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
    Dim sqlcon As SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand

    sqlcon = New SqlConnection
    sqlcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source = RENEE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stocks;Integrated Security = True"

    Try
        sqlcon.Open()
        cmd = New SqlCommand

        cmd.CommandText = " select * from TickerSymbol where TickerSymbol = '" & cboID.Text & "'"

        cmd = New SqlCommand(cmd.CommandText, sqlcon)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()

            'TxtID.Text = dr.GetInt32(0)'
            'TxtSN.Text = dr.GetString(1)'
            'TxtGender.Text = dr.GetString(2)'
            'TxtPhone.Text = dr.GetInt32(3)'
            'TxtAdrress.Text = dr.GetString(4)'

            lblCompanyName.Text = dataReader.GetString(1)
            lblPurchasePrice.Text = dataReader.GetSqlMoney(2)
            lblQtyPurchased.Text = dataReader.GetInt32(3)
            lblPurchaseDate.Text = dataReader.GetDateTime(4)

        End While

        sqlcon.Close()
    Catch ex As SqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
    sqlcon.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Just remove (or comment) that line and the following one. You are not using them, instead add a declaration for `dr` if this is a local variable

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: what is the error?are variables queryString and  connection initialized somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use parameterized queries as this will format values properly e.g. apostrophes in text will escape properly with parameters while without you must handle them, dates will be formatted properly too. Code is much cleaner also.

Example, syntax for Framework 3.5 and higher. If a connection string is used more than once then consider placing it in a private variable or under My.Settings under project properties.

```
Using cn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Data Source = RENEE\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Stocks;Integrated Security = True"}
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn, .CommandText = "select * from TickerSymbol where TickerSymbol = @TickerSymbol"}
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TickerSymbol", cboID.Text)
        cn.Open()
        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If dr.HasRows Then
            While dr.Read
                '
                '
                '
            End While
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```